# Pass argument to another function with javascript (this)

Tags: javascript

I think that my element in renderGrid() contains an html element so I wanna replace "#container" with this. Simply I wanna make my code universal because now I can only use it for "#container" so "#container" has to be replaced with something like template.

```js
function renderGrid(element, settings) {
    var x = settings.columns;
    var y = result.length / x;

    $('.grid').remove();
    for (var cols = 0; cols < x; cols++) {
        for (var rows = 0; rows < y; rows++) {
            numberOfTiles = x * y;
            $('#container').append("<div class='grid'><div class = 'usernameSpace'></div></div>");
        };
    };
    $('.grid').width(800 / x);
    $('.grid').height(800 / x);
}

(function ($) {
    $.fn.tiles = function (options) {
     
        var settings = getOptions(options);

        return this.each(function () {

            var grid = renderGrid(this, options);

            fillTilesWithContent(this, options);

            colorTiles(this, options);

            columnCountSet(this,options);
            
            return grid;
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How to replace "#container" with something I would specify later in console with typing for example $("#container2").tiles({ columns: 5, data: getData(5),backgroundColor:'green',columnCount:2 })
There must be something different I don't know, maybe this from somewhere taken

Comment: Can use Function#call() and pass element in to be used a `this`

Comment: Please, use meaningful variable names. When one sees `x` and `y`, one is generally talking about coordinates. Also, when writing jQuery plugins, it's best to put all your code within the plugin (in other words, within the function after `$.fn.tiles =`.

Comment: you've defined `element` as an argument to `renderGrid`, but then you don't use it. You should be able to just similarly define `element` as an argument for `refreshGrid` and `createGrid`

Comment: Why not pass in with your options.. ?

Comment: x and y are coordinates to specify my grid vertically and horizontally

Comment: Those functions seem to be getting very disconnected from your plugin and why do you even need 3 of them? They are just calling each other internally

Comment: What exactly do you mean: "pass in with options"?

Comment: You're trying to apply an object-oriented concept (`this`) to code that is not structured as an object (`renderGrid` is not a method of an object, but rather just a loose function unattached to anything, except the global object). I would highly suggest looking at https://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/ or https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns to get ideas on how to write jQuery plugins in a maintainable way.

Comment: I thought the code is easier to read and understood when it is splited into these functions

Comment: Not really when you are going to one to call the next which calls the third and the first 2 don't seem to do much and none of them have the original plugin context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe place your related methods into a class and set a class variable, for example

```
Class GridRenderer {
  var _container;
  function call(element, settings) {
    _container = element;
    renderGrid(settings);
  }
  function createGrid(x, y) {
    $('.grid').remove();
    for (var cols = 0; cols < x; cols++) {
      for (var rows = 0; rows < y; rows++) {
        numberOfTiles = x * y;
        _container.append("<div class='grid'><div class = 'usernameSpace'></div></div>");
      };
    };
    $('.grid').width(800 / x);
    $('.grid').height(800 / x);
  };

  function refreshGrid(x, y) {
    createGrid(x, y);
  };

  function renderGrid(settings) {
    var x = settings.columns;
    var y = result.length / x;
    refreshGrid(x, y);
  }
}
```

Then

```
var grid = GridRenderer.call(this, options);
```

Comment: It's a bit complicated for me so I will edit my code and leave only renderGrid() and then please edit this

Comment: Could you check it now?

Comment: With what you have now why not just use `element` instead of `$('#container')` on line 9

Comment: try `$(element)` so it's a jquery object

Comment: Now I have a really strange error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined
    at oa (jquery.js:3)
    at Ha (jquery.js:3)
    at r.fn.init.append (jquery.js:3)
    at renderGrid (MetroUI.js:9)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (MetroUI.js:83)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.$.fn.tiles (MetroUI.js:81)
    at <anonymous>:1:17